# Getting previous format of active cell in Excel after changing the cell color (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am trying to change the color of a cell when you click it (aka the active cell) and then have that cell return to its previous format when you click another cell (format includes previous font, text color, borders, and cell color).
This is the code I used to make the cell color change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("PrevCell").Borders.ColorIndex = 0

    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names("PrevCell")
        .RefersTo = ActiveCell
    End With


End Sub
```

Ideally, I need something that only replaces the cell color to what used to be before the change.

Comment: Just store the previous state in a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim prevCell As Range
Dim clr As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If prevCell Is Nothing Then
    Set prevCell = Target
    clr = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
    prevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
    clr = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Set prevCell = Target
End If
End Sub
```

**Edit as per new requirement:**

To remove the red color from the active cell once you save the file, have the following setup...

**Declare the following Public Variables on a Standard Module like Module1:**

```
Public prevCell As Range
Public clr As Long
```

**Sheet Module Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If prevCell Is Nothing Then
    Set prevCell = Target
    clr = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
    prevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
    clr = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Set prevCell = Target
End If
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook Module Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not prevCell Is Nothing Then prevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
End Sub
```

Comment: @AlessandroGagliardi You're welcome. Glad it solved your issue. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: could you modify the code so that every time I press save on the spreadsheet, it doesn't save the red color on the active cell? Thank you in advance

Comment: @sketneer It gives me an error and says "Object variable or With block variable not set" on ThisWorkbook Module Code `prevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Follow the instructions I added in the answer. You should place all the codes on the correct module. Make sure you declared the `Public Variables` on a `Standard Module`. To do so, insert a new module and declare the `Public Variables` in there.

Comment: OR change that line to `If Not prevCell Is Nothing Then prevCell.Interior.ColorIndex = clr`

Comment: It seems that you tried to save the file before the selection change event executed at least once. Never mind, change the problematic line with the one I suggested above.